# PHP Codeigniter key generation / sending email

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to generate a key and hash it with md5 in codeigniter, but when i send it with the email to the user in a link, it adds more characters to it. And i have no idea why it does this.

```
        if ($this->form_validation->run()){
            // Generates random key //
            $key = md5(uniqid());

            // Loading libraries/models //
            $this->load->library('email', array('mailtype' => 'html'));
            $this->load->model('model_users');

            // Contact info user //
            $this->email->from('asdf', 'Viren Badal');
            $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
            $this->email->subject('asdf');

            // Email message format // 
             $message = "<html>
                            <body>
                                <div>
                                       <a href='".base_url()."visitor/register_user/$key'>".base_url()."visitor/register_user/$key"."</a>
                                </div>
                            </body>
                        </html>
                        ";

            $this->email->message($message);
            if ($this->model_users->add_temp_user($key)){
                if ($this->email->send()){
                echo "An confirmation email has been sent to the following email address: ". $this->input->post('email'). ".";
                } else{
                    echo "Sending confirmation email has failed.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "An error has occurred registering!";
            }
        } else{
            $this->load->view('visitor/signup');
        }
```

This is what stores in the DB:

2a247fcb8a709fc3526d0672e85613d9

And this is what it sends to the email:

http://localhost/lol/visitor/register_user/2a247fcb8a709fc3=26d0672e85613d9

Comment: Try sending it to different email providers. Does it do this on gmail, Yahoo, Microsoft, AOL, or anything? It's quite possible that the provider to which you are sending this email is sanitizing your email before it reaches your inbox.

Comment: I am using a test mail server tool that just listens to port 25 and opens my mails locally, it doesnt send it to my real email. Also the email im registering with is just an random email: test@test.com

Comment: Can you `echo '<textarea>'.$message.'</textarea>';` and verify that everything is precisely as you expect it?

Comment: In email config is `mailtype` set to "html"? That's the only thing I can think of that might be messing with the message contents. Keep in mind the following from the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#id5) If you send HTML email you must send it as a complete web page. Make sure you don’t have any relative links or relative image paths otherwise they will not work.

Comment: Also, where is the rest of your code? `$this->email->message($message);` does not send an email.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus This is what i got from the echo:

`<a href='http://localhost/lol/visitor/register_user/a0f4db7d4578aac96950ca11e898828d'>http://localhost/lol/visitor/register_user/a0f4db7d4578aac96950ca11e898828d</a>`

Comment: Possible `charset` choice problem? Try a different set in email configs perhaps `$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';`

Comment: @VirenBadal, edit your question instead of adding code in comments please.

Comment: @DFriend Do you mean i need to open HTML tags?

Comment: It's difficult to read lengthy code in a comment. Can you update you question with that code, please?

Comment: If your email message is html then yes you need to send a well structured html page including `<html> ..... </html>`

Comment: @DFriend The charset is set to UTF-8.

Comment: After `$this->email->send();` try outputting `echo '<textarea style="width:1000px; height:1000px;">'.print_r($this->email, true).'</textarea>';` and look for `[_finalbody:protected] =>`. Is the value what you expect it to be? This will tell you with 100% certainty if CodeIgniter is altering your URL or if it's something out of CodeIgniter's control.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `[_finalbody:protected] =>` is empty :/

Comment: @DFriend I've added the `<html>` tags and also tried `<!DOCTYPE html>` but both give me the same result..

Comment: Gah! This is why I'm glad I use PHPMailer, lol. Anyways I have a last-ditch effort. Before and/or after `$this->email->send();` do `echo $this->email->print_debugger(array('body'));`

Comment: Not sure if my previous comment is going to reveal anything useful but you might have to look into the source code for further clues @ `/codeigniter/system/libraries/Email.php`

Comment: View the source of an html email and you will likely find that in addition to `<html>` there are `<head>, <body>` and possibly `<style>, <meta>, <title>` tags too. IOW, it must be a complete and well formed html document.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `echo $this->email->print_debugger(array('body'));` does not echo anything.. ive removed the `echo '<textarea style="width:1000px; height:1000px;">'.print_r($this->email, true).'</textarea>';` and pasted the new echo.  Im kinda new to all of this though :/

Comment: To use `print_debugger()` you must make this call  `$this->email->send(FALSE);` Without the `FALSE` the the email data is cleared and there is nothing for debug to output.

Comment: try this tag once <meta charset="UTF-8"> in html document and please use this are also $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);